# how can I clear the delete confirmation state on a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm allowing a swipe on a tableView row to bring up the Delete button when in 'normal', i.e. not 'editing' mode. But in some situations, e.g. when the user presses a button in the UIToolbar, I want to restore the normal state, i.e. remove the delete confirmation.

`showingDeleteConfirmation` is a readonly property, so there's not a `setShowingDeleteConfirmation: NO` option. I'm having no luck with a workaround suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375545/in-uitableviewcell-how-can-i-revert-the-delete-confirmation-mode-back-to-normal-e). The delete confirmation state is stable over a `reloadData` call.

Does anyone know how to force the cell out of the state where it is showing the Delete confirmation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
[myTableView setEditing:FALSE animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Its not work in my case. Im try to override state on prepare for reuse method. Because, after deleting cell from table its still returns showingDeleteConfirmation=YES when im reusing it.

Comment: Interesting - this works, but only if you call the version of setEditing: with animated:.

Answer (score 2):

If you write:

```
[myTableView setEditing:FALSE animated:FALSE];
[myTableView setEditing:TRUE animated:FALSE];
```

then the delete confirmation button disappears and the delete control on the left goes back to
its initial state and the table stays in edit mode.

Comment: This helps fix a bug in SWTableViewCell where, when in edit mode you cannot press on the cell that has showingDeleteConfirmation == YES. I listen to tableView:didSelectRow...: and do this, it surprisingly animates the cell back to it's original position.

Answer (score 1):

Or with the cell indexPath, you can just reload its content (with the Right animation so that it feels like it pushes the delete button away)

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
```

Comment: considerably better suggestion then the others

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, you can do

```
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
```